# Hazelcast backup configuration

Tags: hazelcast

How will Hazelcast configure backups if the number of back ups specified in the configuration is more than the available nodes ?

For example, let us assume I have a Hazelcast cluster set up with 5 nodes. And I have configured the number of async backups to be 8.

In this case, will there be some nodes with more than one backups or will Hazelcast just backup once on each of the 4 other nodes ?

Comment: Nitish, kindly accept one of the answers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nitish, 
It will just backup on 4 nodes. There will be no duplicate backups.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast backup happens at partition level. So your your data gets distributed across your 5 nodes among 271 partitions.
Based on the number of backups mentioned in the config, those many number of backup entries are created and distributed among the partitions. In your case, the data present in Node1 will have 8 backups distributed among 4 nodes so YES, there will be duplicates.
This will be useful for high availability use-cases. Incase the other 4 nodes are crashed, you can still recover the complete data from the backups present in the Node1.

Comment: Is having duplicate backups on the same node useful for high availability? Seems like that node is either available or not available, regardless of how many copies of the data it has.

Comment: Nope, atleast not at 8 backup level. I have seen use-cases with 2 backups max, where loading of data may be expensive so they can't afford to lose multiple nodes at a time.